# Getting error in Terminal when typing Passwd *Username*

Tags: macos, bash, root, daemons

I’ve been trying to change the root password via Terminal on macOS. I launched Terminal by holding cmd + S while booting, which logged me automatically in as root without password.

When I type in `Passwd root` or `Passwd` and then hit enter, I just get an error message that says

> the daemon encountered an error processing request

two times in a row. If a log into my user and then try that it works perfectly but I want to change it from the “cmd+S” menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use passwd in single-user mode or otherwise make changes to accounts on the system, you need to load Open Directory.

```
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist
```

Comment: It will now ask for a new password and then it wants me to retype it but then I only get a error saying : „Passwd: Authentication  Server failed to complete the requested operation. Authentication server failed to complete the requested operation.”